# Collector Doping Concentration and Current Gain

Tags: bjt

I was wondering, in a BJT why does the collector doping concentrarion have no effect in determining the current gain? I am trying to understand this conceptually but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: a lot of the current efforts on doping concentrate on collector currency (basically)  {lol}

Answer (score 1):

The reason the "collector" is called "collector" is it's main function is to collect the charge-carriers emitted by the emitter. More doping of a semiconductor, more charge-carriers it can generate. So we usually make emitter heavy doping, emitter emit, collector collect. The current gain mainly determined by how many carriers the emitter can generate.

And more doping, will lower the resistance as well the breakdown voltage. But if the doping level too low, it will limit the maximum current.

Answer (score 0):

The collector doping effect on the BJT's current gain is somewhat not direct. But there is the general effect of doping, the higher the doping concentration, the less the resistance, the higher the current allowed to pass through. However, the main players are the emitter and the base (I think of the collector as a limiting factor, it does not "force" an increase in the current gain, it simply allows it to increase). This is in simple terms. However, there's more into the BJT than its current gain. Refer to this document for [BJT secondary effects](https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter5/ch5_4.htm).  For example, a very well-known secondary effect is Early Voltage, which increases the current gain at high VCE voltage due to the reduced base width (base width modulation). The higher your collector doping is, the more early effect you will see (until you reach punch-through, then you have other things to worry about). This is not desired since it is important to "control" the BJT's current gain (like all features) than just increasing it. The collector is usually kept low doped to minimise this effect (this is a relationship between base and collector doping).

Moreover, since the BC junction is reverse biased under forward-active conditions, designers consider the breakdown conditions (**avalanche** and zener). Collector doping is also kept low to increase the maximum voltage the junction can handle before it breaks down (also called blocking voltage). But this is more of a concern in power devices, not signal-level devices.